# VBA code: IF cell x = cell y clear cell y

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that is used to allocate people specific duties. This is automatically filled with names from a long run of VB. In the unlikely event less than 4 people are on a specific shift my code will end up putting the same name in 2 cells instead of just one. (due to how I have made this work with some concatenation)

I want to error check once the code has run to see if the same name appears in the cell above it. If it does I want to clear the cell above.

The cells with the names in have to be ranges in VB as they span more than one column.

I've tried the code below which does not run, I feel it should be fairly straight forwards to check if one cell equals another cell and if it does to clear a specified cell. I just cant get it to work

```
Sub errorcatch()

    If Range("F33:G33").Value = Range("F32:G32").Value Then

      Range("F32:G32").Clear

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are those connected cells, or do they literally span two cells? E.g. `F33 = John` and `G33 = Smith` ?

Comment: *I feel it should be fairly straight forwards to check if one cell equals another cell and if it does to clear a specified cell.* And you're right, it *kinda* is. The problem is that you're not dealing with individual cells here, but 2D variant arrays. Use single-cell ranges in comparisons (note: that will blow up with a *type mismatch* error if any of the cells involved contain a worksheet error value e.g. `#VALUE` or `#N/A`).

Answer (score 1):

```
If Range("F33").Value = Range("F32").Value And Range("G33").Value = Range("G32").Value Then
    Range("F32:G32").Clear
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the cell in column F matches the one below, and the cell in column G matches the one below.
It will work its way down each cell in column F until it reaches the bottom of your data.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Range will go from F1 to bottom of data in column F (column 6).
        Set rData = .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))
    End With

    'Cycle through each cell in rData.
    For Each rCell In rData
        'If rCell is the same as the cell below, and the cell to the right is the same
        'as the cell to the right and one cell down then clear the contents.
        If rCell = rCell.Offset(1) And rCell.Offset(, 1) = rCell.Offset(1, 1) Then
            rCell.Resize(, 2).ClearContents
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Further reading:  [Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset)

Answer (score -1):

You could try to refer only to the cell value not the range:

```
Sub errorcatch()
     [g32] = IIf ([g33] = [g32], "", [g32]) 
End Sub
```

Comment: `[A1]` still references `Range("A1")`, but the default property of the range object is its `.Value` property

Comment: @Nacorid it's also an implicit `Application.Evaluate` syntax that is good enough for scratchpad-code in the immediate pane, but highly toxic in an actual code module.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I didn't know that! always nice to learn all the implicit happenings :)